# Date format different from version 1.2 in version 1.3

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, package, momentjs

I want to use [rzymek:moment](https://atmospherejs.com/rzymek/moment) and the companion package [rzymek:moment-locale-de](https://atmospherejs.com/rzymek/moment-locale-de) in my upgraded Meteor 1.3 app. Here is my code:

```
import { moment } from 'meteor/rzymek:moment';

const date = moment(new Date()).locale('de').format('ddd DD MMMM');
console.log(date);
```

Right now it still prints the English date format. If I remove the import statement, it works like it did in Meteor 1.2 and prints the German version. But I want to use the new module structure. So the `rzymek:moment-locale-de` package is not loaded obviously.
How can I load that package into `{moment}`?

Same issue with [tap:i18n](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n) and [tap:i18n-db](https://atmospherejs.com/tap/i18n-db).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now Meteor 1.3 easily lets you use npm packages, have you tried using npm's moment?

on command line

```
npm install moment
```

then in your code

```
import moment from 'moment'
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. In the atmosphere package of moment the localization didn't work. That's why I used rzymek with 1.2. The npm package has localization :)

Comment: Yeah, great thing about meteor 1.3 is that you can straight up use npm packages now :). Glad it worked :)